# use User.Identity.Name in ASP.Net Core RC1 app running on IIS7.5

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, asp.net-core

I'm writing an intranet site using ASP.Net Core. I've created the site in VS2015 and selected to use windows authentication. I now need access to the current user account name in my server code. I'm fairly new to this, so I could be wrong, but I believe I should be using User.Identity.Name? When I look at this though, it's null. I'd previously been running the site using self-hosting and had read somewhere that this was to be expected if you were hosting use the generated web.cmd entry point, but would work okay under IIS. I'm now running it under IIS though, but I'm seeing the same behaviour. Can anyone point me at what I'm missing?

This is my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="..\approot\web.cmd" arguments="--server.urls http://address:5001" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout.log" startupTimeLimit="3600" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"></httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The site is running okay under IIS using this config, apart from the Identity problem. Within ISS I have disabled everything but Windows Authentication for the site using the Authentication settings accessed from the site Features view

In case it's needed, here is a section of my project.json file with dependencies, commands and frameworks:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "System.DirectoryServices.Linq": "1.2.2.1",
    "AutoMapper": "4.2.1"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef" : "EntityFramework.Commands"

  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
        "dependencies": {
            "Services": "1.0.0-*"

        }
    }
  },
```

Comment: I am receiving error "Login failed for user ''." in my httpPlatform log file with the same setup as you have described.  Have you found a solution?

Comment: Yes. There's a bug in the current version of the iisplatformhandler module. You need to wrap your call to Configure in your startup in a call that maps your baseurl to a virtual directory. I'll post an answer now, as it'll make more sense with code fragments. One moment...

Comment: Done. Not sure it's the same issue you're having, but it's worth a shot

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in the IISPlatformHandler module that requires your to map your app's base URL to a virtual directory (as I understand the solution, anyway!!). Rather annoyingly I'd come across this before posting the question, but it didn't seem to work. I can only assume I'd been trying so many things that I'd mucked up my test the first time round. The site now works perfectly under IIS

Here's the code change to make in your startup class:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {
            app.Map("/SomeBasePath", (app1) => this.ConfigureInternal(app1, env, loggerFactory));
        }

        public void ConfigureInternal(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)       {
             // your original call to Configure here
        }
```

So you're basically renaming your original Configure method, and calling it from a new Configure method that does the mapping.

Let's say your site was running as http://webserver:1234/Home previously. After this change you would need to access it as http://webserver:1234/SomeBasePath/Home. This was fine for our site, so I'm not sure how you'd do it without the extra node in the URL, if you needed to.